# Would abu al-Hassan al-Asha'ari regard himself as among the Asha'arites?

Tags: history, islamic-scholar, theology

The [Ash'arite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash%27ari) أشعرية‎ or Asha'irah ٱلْأَشَاعِرَة are a known theoligcal sect of creed that refers by name to abu al-Hassan al-Asha'ary and most of its followers can be found among followers of the shafi'i and maliki school of fiqh. And they regard themselves as representatives of ahl-as-Sunnah wa Jma'ah beside other sects (of creed) such as the Maturidi's and the Salafi's.

Now I've read somewhere -correct me if I'm wrong-  that abu al-Hassan al-Asha'ari passed through three phases in his life.

1. A phase in which he was a follower of the creed of [al-Mu'tazilah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu%CA%BFtazila).
2. A phase in which he started debating al-Mu'tazilah based on ['ilm al-Kalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam).
3. A phase in which he defended the creed of ahl as-Sunnah wal Jama'a.

And as far as I know in each of these phases or at least in the last two he has compiled books defining his creed and theology.

My question now is: Those scholars who claim to be 'Ashra'arites like the imams and scholars:

- Among the Shafi'is: al-Juwayni,  al-Ghazali, al-Bayhaqi, an-Nawawi, as-Suyuti, al-Fakhr a-Razi, ibn 'Abdassalaam, as-Subki, ibn 'Asakir ...
- Among the Maliki's: al-Baqilani, abu Bakr ibn al-'Arabi
- Among the Hanbali's: ibn al-Jawzi (at least wikipedia claims he was because of his works in ilm al-Kalam)
- ...

which of his creeds or phases did they follow?

It could be great if your answer could include some details.

Comment: Correction: Salafiyyah isn't a creed. It is true that all Salafis are Atharis but not all Atharis are Salafis. Many opposed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proof for the "three phrases" that the Salafīs claim that he went through. Rather, he abandoned the Mútazilah to become a Sunni and then supported the madh'hab of Ahl al-Sunnah so much that eventually it became synonymous with his madh'hab.

All the scholars you listed shared the same creed as he did post-conversion to Ahl al-Sunnah.

Except for Ibn al-Jawzī, who was not an Ashárī, but was somewhere between Atharī and Ashárī.

Comment: Try including references for your claims and Ibn Al Jawzi was Hanbali by fiqh but he was an Ashari in creed.

Comment: No, he criticised the Ashárīs too.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, he was an Athari and then he became an Ashari.

Comment: Wikipedia is not an accurate source. He did certainly share many similar views to them, however he was not completely one himself and did criticise them too.

Comment: You're suggesting that Ibn Al Jawzi was ignorant in aqeedah. There's no such thing as "somewhere between Athari and Ashari" you're either one or not.

Comment: I am not suggesting he was ignorant, but rather he does not fit into either of the two categories.

Comment: I think Ibn e Khan is trying to say that he believed on some parts of the athari and some parts of ashari aqeeda and disbelieved some parts of the athari aqeeda and disbelieved some parts of ashari aqeeda, It's mix of aqeeda based on his own preference of what is right and wrong.